# Android/Facebook: Post message on wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to post a message on the my own wall via an Android application. I have the method loginToFacebook() to login. On click on a button, if the user is logged in I want a message to be posted. I am not really familiar with facebook API so I've looked the facebook developers documentation and other sites on internet to propose the code that follows. Yet, no message is posted on my wall. Obviously I miss something but I don't know what as I have no error on my LogCat.

```
public class ShareActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("477110419013909");
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;


  public void onClick(View arg0) {
        loginToFacebook();
        if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("message","Hey Facebook!");
            try {
                String strRet = facebook.request("/me/feed",bundle,"POST");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("Facebook", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("Facebook", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("Facebook", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

}

public void loginToFacebook() {
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
    }
}
}
```

I tried to do

```
if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("message","Hey Facebook!");

            facebook.dialog((Activity) this, "feed", bundle,
                    new DialogListener() {

                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        }

                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}
                        public void onError(DialogError e) {}
                        public void onCancel() {}
            });
 }
```

Did not work either

Comment: bro how did you solve your issue? i have same issue

Answer (score -1):

I have use this activity class for post image :

```
public class PostStatusFBActivity extends Activity {
 private static String[] PERMISSIONS = 
            new String[] {"photo_upload","publish_stream"};

Bundle parems;
//String status;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
public final static String FB_APP_ID = "xxxxxxxx"; 
private Facebook fb;
private Handler mHandler;
//private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
//private static String app_secret = "51a4b033e6cdbddf5761101d3eb09881";

/**
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    parems=intent.getBundleExtra("params");
    fb= new Facebook(PostStatusFBActivity.FB_APP_ID);

    SessionStore.restore(fb, this);

    if (fb.isSessionValid()) 
        post_status();
    else
        fb.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS,new AppLoginListener());

}

private class AppLoginListener implements DialogListener {

    public AppLoginListener() {

    }

    public void onCancel() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please accept to login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        /**
         * We request the user's info so we can cache it locally and
         * use it to render the new html snippets
         * when the user updates her status or comments on a post. 
         */

        mAsyncRunner=new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb);
        post_status();
    }

    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        Log.e("BTS", "dialog error: " , e);               
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        Log.e("BTS ", "facebook error: " , e);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}




protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
    //Facebook fb = Session.wakeupForAuthCallback();
    fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}



public void post_status() {

    Log.e("BTS ____  ", " Post satus called ");
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", parems,"POST",new mRequestListener(),null);
}

public class mRequestListener implements RequestListener{

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
        Log.d("BTS", "******************* FACEBOOK::onMalformedURLException *******************");
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        Log.d("BTS", "******************* FACEBOOK::onIOException *******************");
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
        Log.d("BTS", "******************* FACEBOOK::onFileNotFoundException *******************");
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        Log.d("BTS", "******************* FACEBOOK::onFacebookError *******************");
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    String msg="";

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        Log.d("BTS", "******************* FACEBOOK::onComplete *******************");

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Facebook-Example",
                "News feed: " + response.toString());
        JSONObject json;

        /*JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final String pictureURL = json.getString("picture");
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pictureURL)) {
         * */
        try {
            json = Util.parseJson(response);
            Log.d("Facebook-Example",
                    "News feed: " + json.toString(2));

             final String post_id = json.getString("post_id");
             if (TextUtils.isEmpty(post_id)) {
                msg="Error in update status";
             }else{
                 msg="Status updated";
             }
             mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
             });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

And here is Bundle params that I pass from previous Activity
`byte[] data = null;

Bundle params = new Bundle();

            params.putByteArray("photo", data);
            params.putString("caption", status);`

Other values that you can put on Bundle 
`params.putString("message", "This string will appear as the status message");
        params.putString("link", "This is the URL to go to");
        params.putString("name", "This will appear beside the picture");
        params.putString("caption", "This will appear under the title");
        params.putString("description", "This will appear under the caption");
        params.putString("picture", "This is the image to appear in the post");`