# Facebook post using android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new on developing android app.
i already implement facebook using facebook library.
Now i want to make a custom post.

[Image that i want to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUnus.png)

i want to have a picture and little description on the right of the image.
and also a link.

This is my code for post on wall.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
```

These code only for posting a message on my wall.
Please help me for it C=

Thank you

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560810/android-facebook-post-message-on-wall

Comment: @ViragBrahme thank you. But i dont know how to implement that code.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

Following are the steps to include Facebook SDK into android project:

1) Download the Facebook SDK from the https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/ 
   and extract it to local drive.

2) Import "facebook" as a android project into your Eclipse, this is your Facebook SDK, and You have to reference it to your android project.

3) Now create your android project.

4) Right click on it, go to Properties-->android and Add the "facebook "Library as a reference to your project. click Apply.

Check the video link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-vNi1W4fco

Comment: No, that's not what i mean.
I already can post a post to facebook.
But i want to share something through my application.
I want to share picture and a little description and also a link.
I What my post look like on my hyperlink.